# How return GUID from this method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method. I want to return a new `GUID` as a successful response to the client:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Guid))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOrder(Order order)
{
    ....
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(Guid.NewGuid());
    return Ok(response);
}
```

The client ajax:

```
statusCode: 
{
    200: function() {
    alert("Saved");
    },
    404:
        function() {
            alert("Error");
        }
},
success: function (response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

It doesn't return the `GUID` to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: what about `return Ok(Guid.NewGuid());` ?

Comment: @FrankNielsen How is this different from my code? I have done already what you said. "var response = Request.CreateResponse(Guid.NewGuid());
    return Ok(response);"

Comment: why is it `async Task<IHttpActionResult>`? Do you use any `await` in your method?

Comment: @ingvar Yes i have used await And this is Web Api post method.

Comment: If i remember correct, Ok takes an object and translate it to json. So your Response object is translated to json. So it should be `return Ok(new { Id = Guid.NewGuid()});`

Comment: @FrankNielsen It returns [object object] in the alert as response. is my ajax response correct?

Comment: Try `alert( yourresponseobject.id)` or `alert(JSON.stringify(yourresponseobject));`

Comment: @FrankNielsen Yes it worked. Thanks. can you post it as answer with more explanation of how it works and so that i can accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a json result from a api method by parsing the response directly to the ok method.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOrder(Order order)
{
    ....
    var response = new { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
    return Ok(response);
}
```

The response object will then be serialized to json, and can be accessed as an object.

```
  $.get('*/PostOrder',order).done( function(response) {
    alert( response.id );
  });
```

Comment: Ya, many questions get downvotes - and i have no clue why. It should be required to leave a comment when downvoting, that would properly stop some of it.